# Java scanner reads garbage value from a file

Tags: java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a file of tokens, here is my code:

```
public class Prac1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{     //File file = new File();
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            HashMap<String,String> symbolTable = new HashMap<String,String>();
            //reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(
                new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("/Users/Documents/Lab1/testCase1.txt")));

            while(scan.hasNext()){
        String i= scan.next();
                System.out.println("test--->"+i);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

**The file reads tokens but at the beginning and at the end of output it gives garbage value.**I want to eliminate these values.

Comment: Can you include the beginning and end of the file, and the beginning and end of your output?

Comment: @Gayatri, please consider adding "homework" tag if it is indeed for homework to get more targeted answers.

Comment: @Chris:the o/p looks somewhat like this :test--->^&&*&^
test--->%$^%&
test--->1         //valid
test--->xy       //valid
test--->1002 //valid
test--->E        //valid
test--->1004 //valid
test--->2        //valid
test--->&^&*
test--->&^YU
test--->&^*^

Comment: Wow. Are there *any* text encodings involved here?

Answer (score 0):

Change your text preferences to plain text. 
In Mac go to text -> preferences -> plain text option
Then create a new text file and it should work!